# Racket - encode a message

Tags: racket

I am trying to write a function which produces an encoded version of a string where 
all the letters are swapped with the letter at the same relative position at the other end of the alphabet. 
For example, an A would become a Z and a Z would become an A; a B would become a Y and a Y would become a B. 
All numeric characters stay the same and all non-alpha numerics characters are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the function `char->integer`.

Here is a little expression to get you started:

```
          (for/list ([c "hello world"])
              (define i (- (char->integer c) (char->integer #\a)))
              (integer->char (- (char->integer #\z) i)))
```

You need to figure out how to handle characters outside a-z correctly.

Comment: Thank you for answering!!  I edited my question since I realized I don't understand abstract list function at all... I think I need more help :(

Comment: Make a function `encode-char` that takes a char `c` as input and returns the encoded character. Then you can use `(list->string (map encode-char (string->list s)))` as you did in your upcase function.

Comment: Ok so I've edited my code and now it works perfectly :) Thank you so much for your help!!